# Byte to end up a inputstream read()

Tags: java, android, sockets, byte

Hei,

My goal is to send packets from a server to my android smartphone and vise versa.
I use sockets but if i send more packets in the same time then my server can't read all.

So i wrote a code to read every single byte "inputstream.read()" and if a specific byte was read, the byte array should proceed. I have the problem, that i have no such "byte" to send that my read function knows that the packet is finished to proceed.

I would use byte number 254 (-2) but i don't know if that is ok and makes no problems. Has anybody an idea which byte i can securely use?

Comment: a byte which you don't use? the last one?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno yes, but what is the last byte?

Comment: byte is from -128 to 127 (use Byte.MAX_VALUE and Byte.MIN_VALUE too)